# Null check for reflected property's value with Any() keyword

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection, nullreferenceexception

I have a **List of Entity Framework DAL objects** where I am using a **query parameter string** that can include commas. I am trying to get all objects from the DAL List that satisfy the values in the query parameter string.

I have the following Linq statement that yields what I am expecting:

```cs
dalList = dalList
   .Where(aa => queryParamString.Split(',')
      .Any((x => (aa.GetType().GetProperty(kvp.Key).GetValue(aa, null)).ToString().ToLower() == x.ToLower())))
   .ToList();
```

The above statement works fine **if the list does not contain a null value** for the reflected property.

How can I include a null check into this Linq statement to avoid the NullReferenceException on the first ToString() method call?

Edit: kvp.Key  is a string representation to a database column

Comment: `?.ToString()?.ToLower()`

Comment: @Renat That appeared to work. If you post as an answer with a simple explanation as to how the ? operand is behaving here I would gladly upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: `?.` is one of the [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: Second duplicate says VB.NET, but of course the exact same syntax exists in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` could be used to make null checks more concise and to avoid null reference exception.

From MSDN `a?.x` is being evaluated as:

> - If `a` evaluates to `null`, the result of `a?.x` ... is `null`.
> - If `a` evaluates to non-null, the result of `a?.x` ... is the same as the result of `a.x` ...

So because `.GetValue(aa, null)` can return `null`, to avoid null reference exception in calling `ToString()` on `null` we can use `.GetValue(aa, null)?.ToString()`, which in case of null value just returns null without NRE.

Then even if `?.` operator is a short-circuiting operator, `ToString()` can return `null` in general, so it's better to use null conditional operator again in `ToString()?.ToLower()`. Which turns into:

```
GetValue(aa, null)?.ToString()?.ToLower() == x.ToLower()
```

and `==` ([string equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-5.0) here) allows for `null`s as parameters so we are safe from null reference exception here.

Comment: I guess it is best to be sure, but Microsoft recommendation is that `ToString` should not return `null` even though the return type is `string?` presumably for backwards compatibility (perhaps they can fix that someday).